# Java 8 generics + exceptions compile time error when using a lambda expression

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8

A couple of days ago, I started refactoring some code to use the new Java 8 Streams library. Unfortunately, I ran into a compile time error when performing Stream::map with a method which is declared to throw a generic E that is further specified to be a RuntimeException.

Interesting enough, the compile time error goes away when I switch to using a method reference.

Is this a bug, or is my method reference not equivalent to my lambda expression?

(Also, I know I can replace p->p.execute(foo) with Parameter::execute. My actual code has additional parameters for the execute method).

---

**Error message**

```
Error:(32, 43) java: unreported exception E; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

---

**Code**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class JavaBugTest
{
    interface AbleToThrowException<E extends Exception>
    {
    }

    interface Parameter {
        public <E extends Exception> Object execute(AbleToThrowException<E> algo) throws E;
    }

    interface ThrowsRuntimeException extends AbleToThrowException<RuntimeException>
    {
    }

    static ThrowsRuntimeException foo;


    public static Object manualLambda(Parameter p)
    {
        return p.execute(foo);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Parameter> params = new ArrayList<>();
        params.stream().map(p -> p.execute(foo)); // Gives a compile time error.
        params.stream().map(JavaBugTest::manualLambda); // Works fine.
    }

}
```

---

**System setup**

- OS: Windows x64
- Java compiler version: Oracle JDK 1.8.0_11
- IDE: Intellij

Comment: Which compiler are you using? I don't get a problem with Eclipse's compiler. But I do with Oracle's.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis My IDE is Intellij. But, Intellij is claiming that javac is doing the actual compiling : "Information:Using javac 1.8.0_11 to compile java sources". Nevertheless, I guess I should try compiling manually from the command line.

Comment: Update: Compiling manually from the command line gives the exact same error.

Comment: Note that the two `map` invocations are not equivalent. Still, I think this is a bug in the compiler.

Comment: workaround: `p -> p.<RuntimeException>execute(foo)`

Comment: Note that the `manualLambda` case works by the simple fact that the `manualLambda` method does not declare any exceptions.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the bytecode Eclipse generates for both calls is identical. I agree that this is likely a bug in javac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple solution is to explicitly provide a type argument for `Parameter#execute(..)`.

```
params.stream().map(p -> p.<RuntimeException>execute(foo)); // Gives a compile time error.
```

Without the explicit type argument, it seems like the JDK compiler cannot infer a type argument from the invocation context, though it should. This a bug and should be reported as such. I have now reported it and will update this question with new details when I have them.

[Bug Report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8066974)

Comment: I think someone at the JAX2014 conference some months ago already mentioned this bug and already posted the link to the bugreport - but I cannot find it at the moment. But there is a list somewhere describing the differences between the eclipse compiler and javac concerning java 8 features.

Comment: @mschenk74 Did you happen to find the bugreport in the mean time? We are also experiencing this bug and would like to see the status.

Comment: I haven't found the bug report I mentioned yet.